# Can we prettify makefile code?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I was wondering if there is a `makefile` prettify language tag that I can add to highlight variables, flags or whatever prettify is able to identify.

As mentioned in the comment by Frederic, I'm looking for the appropriate language tag to use to highlight `makefile` syntax.

Comment: According to the [readme](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html), it should already work on makefile. I'm guessing it's the same as lang-sh?

Comment: Nothing will make them any prettier.